# root node automatically resets to null while insertion

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to add new nodes to the tree but whenever one insertion is completed, root node automatically resets to null and at the end my tree is empty. I'm trying to construct BST. 
My main function:

```
int main()
{
    char c;
    int item;
    struct BSTNode *root=NULL;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n1 Insert an element ");
        printf("\n2 Delete an element");
        printf("\n3 InOrder Traversal");
        printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &c);
        switch(c)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("\nEnter the item:");
                scanf("%d", &item);
                if(root){printf("Root data before: %d",root->data); }  //Print statement -1
                root = insert(root,item);                
                printf("Root data after: %d",root->data); //Print statement-2
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("\nEnter the info to be deleted:");
                scanf("%d", &item);
                root = delete(root, item);
                break;

            case 3:
                InOrder(root);
                break;

            default:
                printf("Enter a valid choice: ");
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

and my insert function looks like:

```
 struct BSTNode* insert(struct BSTNode *root, int data)
 {
     if(root==NULL)
     {
        root=create(data);
     }
     if(data<root->data)
        root->left=insert(root->left,data);
     if(data>root->data)
        root->right=insert(root->right,data);
     return root;
 }
```

Here in my main function, two print statements are there. In that, statement 2 is printing the data of root node but when again I want to add new node, statement 1 doesn't print the data of root node. And after that new value of root node is shown in statement 2 also.

Comment: In `scanf("%d", &c);` you are using the wrong type, or the wrong format specifier. The code has *undefined behaviour* and will possibly cause damage by overwriting something.

Comment: What happens in the equality case. You tested `if(data < root->data)` and `if(data > root->data)` but you overlooked `data == root->data`

Comment: But in binary search tree, duplicate data is not considered. If `data==root->data` then shouldn't we ignore that? And changing `char c` to `int c` worked, maybe that was causing some error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why its `char c`? when your cases are integer, try using `int c` instead. Also you are taking input using `%d` so it should be integer

Comment: Yes, earlier I was planing to take character as input, but then I went for integer without changing it. It was silly mistake

Comment: If this works, kindly accept the answer! Thank you!